# Frequent Unexpected Asp.net Session Drops Hosted on Asure

Tags: asp.net, azure, session, session-cookies, haproxy

Since we have moved to azure, we have numerous session lost issues **only** on production.

We have InProc, cookie based, sticky session, large timeout, no high traffic and no high memory/process usage.

We use **HAProxy** as loadbalancer.

I have done **basic research** and none of the following seems to be the cause:

- session timeout
- application pool settings/recycling
- memory size and usage thresholds
- no eaten exceptions
- there is no changes to file system to cause a restart

I'm particularly more suspicious about how loadbalancer/ssl and application work together and if http headers are fine, but I don't know any tools to really monitor that.

I'm assigned to find a solution at the same time I have no privilege to access the machines.

Logs(Log4Net) are all stored in database but doesn't help to give a clear understanding of what is going on the system and cannot follow a user session using them.

I'm allowed to find the problem by adding required logs to code or to develop some kind of monitoring module or to use profiling/debugging tools.

Only once a month there will be a production deployment so I'm trying to use the opportunity as best as possible.

Question:

1. Is there any useful monitoring/profiling tool that can give me a clear view of what is happening in the system by aggregating information I may need? for example following a user/session between requests from time of login until session drop plus information about headers and other system application parameters.
2. if there is not such a tool out there, please give me your ideas to write one?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in load balanced environment. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36488002/3431596) for a similar question,

InProc mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. Which means that session data is maintained inside your web server on a given VM and is not shared outside of the VM. So when you have multiple server for load balancing, the session state isn't shared with each other. To solve this, you must store your session state external to the web server.

Use Redis, or SQL Database, or something else.